# How can I create a MOBA health bar in Godot?

Tags: progress-bar, 2d, godot, gdscript, topdown

I want to make a health bar for my 2D top down character which is similar to the MOBA games.

For instance, this is the image of a health bar in the game called Leauge of Legend:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ekpe.png

> This is the health bar of a level 1 character in the game

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dv4G.png

> This is the health bar of a level 13 character in the game (sorry for the blurry image)

As you can see, when the character's health increases, the health bar has more "sticks"  inside it, which let the player know how much health the character has with only a glance.

I have no idea how to create this kind of health bar, so it would be great if you can give me a code sample or at least a few hints. I couldn't find any tutorials related to what I intend to make, so any of your efforts are deeply appreciated.

Comment: maybe create your character and add [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYVZRCj1wok) Control node inside your character node? so that your health bar follows along, Also have you looked at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEZXVK1-tlU)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Godot you have the node TextureProgress, which can be used as an Healthbar by choosing the Textures for your progress bar and an overlay (a border) for the healhbar.

Now you could put you sticks on the "Over" Texture and change the image by calling a function, everytime the maximum amount of life changed:

```
#Images you define that should be set. 
export var max_sticks_bar : StreamTexture 
export var min_sticks_bar : StreamTexture 

func change_upper_image() -> void:
        if max_value >= 500: # as an example I change the image to one with more sticks
            texture_over = max_sticks_bar 
        else:
            texture_over = min_sticks_bar
```

This is not optimal, because you would need an Image for every single threshold you would like to show. And the lines would be randomly set without a real reference to the actual max life.

The better way would be to draw the lines yourself by using the _draw() function of the TextureProgress. This allows you to draw the lines dynamically everytime the update() function is called. In my example I will draw a stick for every 50 life:

```
# function to call, if you change the max_life
func set_max_life(life: float) -> void: 
    max_value = life
    update()

        
func _draw():
    var bar_height = rect_size.y
    var bar_width = rect_size.x
    #could be dynamic. You maybe want smaller lines if there are a to many
    var line_width = 10
    var line_color = Color.black
    #should also be dynamic. Determines after how much life a line is drawn
    var life_per_line = 50  
    #lets say we wnat to draw lines from the top to the middle of the bar
    var line_height = bar_height/2
    
    #how many lines should be drawn
    var lines_to_draw : int = int(max_value / life_per_line)
    
    if (lines_to_draw > 0):
        var pixel_per_line = int(bar_width / lines_to_draw)
        var draw_pos_x = pixel_per_line
        for i in lines_to_draw:
            if (draw_pos_x < bar_width):
                draw_line(Vector2(draw_pos_x,0), Vector2(draw_pos_x, line_height), line_color, line_width)
            draw_pos_x = draw_pos_x + pixel_per_line
```

This would look like this (The "Over" Image in my example is just the border around the bar. The sticks are drawn, when I change the maximum life by clicking one of the buttons):
[image]

Note: By using the Draw Function you will draw on to the canvas item (TextureProgress Node) so whatever you draw is above any of the images you set in the node itself.